# Android : issue when using Dropbox SDK - Dropbox Chooser requires Fragments

Tags: android

am trying to use the Dropbox Chooser API in my Android App. I have followed the steps outlined in the Dropbox documentation (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/android). But am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Dropbox Chooser requires Fragments. If below API level 11, pass in a FragmentActivity from the support library.
```

But am not using Fragments. What does it mean by "pass a FragmentActivity"? Where should I pass it? Any link to sample code will help.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you have to use fragments, to be able to use the Dropbox Choser API.

at the bottom of the document you linked, they even mention your error message.

> The Android Chooser SDK includes the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) and is written to support [Android API version 8](http://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html) and higher. To support Android API versions 8, 9, and 10, your app must extend Activity or `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` instead of `Fragment`. If it doesn't, you'll see the following error in LogCat when using the Android Chooser on these older versions:
>
> > The Chooser requires Fragments. If below API level 11, pass in a FragmentActivity from the support library.
>
> Also, the Android Support Library that is bundled with the Chooser may conflict with the support library in your project if your project has a different version. If you see a "Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies" error in the Console, delete *android-support-v4.jar* in the libs directory of *DropboxChooserSDK* and copy the version of *android-support-v4.jar* from your project into that folder.

you should consider start using fragments. at least for the portion of code where you want to use dropbox.
[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) you find a guide about fragments and how to getting started with them.